# Dice Rolling Simulation

Tags: function-construction, simulation, homework

I'm simulating a sequence of dice rolls by choosing a random integer between 1 and 6. I need to use *FoldList* to generate a function that returns a list which describes how the cumulative total varies through the generated random sequence after *n* tosses. How do I accomplish this?

Comment: You can also use `Accumulate`. However, where is your question?

Comment: Writing the function is the question. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: `FoldList[Plus, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}]`

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher Why didn't you include 6? Correct me if I'm wrong but how does this include the cumulative total after *n* tosses?

Comment: That was just an example to show you how to do the accumulation with `FoldList`. You have still to throw the dice. For example, 12 tosses: `FoldList[Plus, RandomInteger[{1, 6}, 12]]` Although I would recommend to use `Accumulate[RandomInteger[{1, 6}, 12]]`.

Comment: @Alan Yes, I tagged it as homework.

Comment: @Moo The former link you gave me isn't working but I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 2):

Henrik Schumacher has shown how to use `FoldList` to do the accumulation. All you need to get what you want is  a way to generate `n` random integers in the ranges 1–6. You can do that with a single call to [`RandomInteger`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RandomInteger.html):

```
RandomInteger[{1, 6}, n]
```

Your function should take `n`, the number of tosses as it argument.

Comment: Didn't the OP ask for the cumulative total?  I think the answer by Henrik Schumacher (written as a function) gives a most concise answer:  RollTotal[numberOfRolls_]:= Accumulate[RandomInteger[{1,6},numberOfRolls]

Comment: @MarkR. Yes, that's why I reference Henrik's comment.

Answer (score -1):

I think you want `NestList`:

```
mylist[n_: Integer] := NestList[# + RandomInteger[{1, 6}] &, 0, n]
```